# Автоматическое форматирование в visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, shortcuts

В Vidual Studio вот такой код:

`cout<<"hello"<<endl;`

в момент ввода ";" автоматически форматируется:

`cout << "hello" << endl;`

Можно ли как-то вызвать такое автоматическое форматирование вручную, нажатием клавиши или кнопки в контекстном меню?

Comment: посмотри в сторону плагина prettier или нажымай Ctrl+Shift+P и набирай Format Document

Comment: Edit -> Advanced -> Format Selection